# Could not parse property path "data.languages.[french]". Unexpected token "." - Symfony error

Tags: symfony, validation

I have set the languages level collection type:

The user is faced with many textfields where he can specify his level in some languages.

```
$builder->add('languages', 'collection', array(
    'type' => 'text',                    
));
```

Then in the entity :

```
* @Assert\Collection(
*     fields={
*         "french"  = @Assert\Required(),
*         "english" = @Assert\Required()
*     },
*     allowExtraFields = true
* )
*/
private $languages;
```

The corresponding mutators:

```
public function getLanguages()
{
    return $this->languages;
}

public function setLanguages($languages)
{
    $this->languages= $languages;

    return $this;
}
```

When instantiating the entity, the languages fields are initialized with empty strings in the constructor.

In the form page I get the error mentionned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the porblem by upgrading Symfony from 2.5 to 2.6 version.
Now the annotation constraint @Assert\Collection works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `data.languages.french` not `data.languages.[french]`.

Comment: Where do I have to put data.languages.french ?

Answer (score 0):

check your view. I think you should try this :

```
{% if data.languages is not empty %} {{data.languages['frensh']}} {% endif %}
```

Comment: I only display the FormView {{ form(form) }}.

Comment: If I remove the constraint @Assert\Collection, everything is OK. But I need to keep this validation rule.